# How to find the definition of an existing method?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, calabash

I am new to programming and Ruby both. In some existing code, it says something like this:

```
kid_raising_btn=query("switch marked:'KIDRAISING'",:isOn).first
```

From this, I understand that a variable `kid_raising_btn` is defined, which will query and return true or false, then call the method `first` (but this is confusing).

How can I find what `first` does?

Comment: [The Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org) site is your friend. Even better, Ruby comes with on-line documentation that make it easy to find what `first` does: `ri first` at the command-line will show every place that rdoc found the `first` method defined in Ruby and gems classes. You'll have to figure out what class is receiving `first` from looking at the code, but the docs are easy to find.

Comment: Another thing that can be helpful if you aren't sure what object is being returned or what options you have with it is drop into a REPL like [irb](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/) or [pry](http://pryrepl.org) and just play with the object. In pry you can also use [`show-source`](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Source-browsing#view-method-and-class-source-code-with-show-source) to view the definition of a method.

Comment: "which will query and return true or false" is incorrect.  the query will return an array of ui elements that match the query. if the array is empty, then no matches are found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

".first" is kind of convenient method. 
Answer for the UI query comes as an array. 
So the ".first" represent the first element of the array. 
There are few methods like ".count"

Ex: 
your Query :

```
ans = query("button",:accessibilityLabel)
```

Assume You will get result like this

```
[
    [0] "icon rewards new",
    [1] "icon my receipts new",
    [2] "icon my account",
    [3] "icon order@2x",
    [4] "icon check in"
]
```

if you use ".first" like this

```
ans2 = query("button",:accessibilityLabel).first
```

you will get a String with first element as a result instead of an array.

```
"icon rewards new"
```

Now you can see you get the first element as the answer

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like the method chaining here might be contributing to your confusion, so first let's rewrite that line of code like this:

```
    query_response = query("switch marked: 'KIDRAISING'", :isOn)
    kid_raising_btn = query_response.first
```

Now, it's easier to see that the #query method returns an object that has a #first method.  You can take a look at this object to see what class it is (`query_response.class`), and then either look up the appropriate documentation for the class or find the method definition in your codebase.  For example, if #query returns an array, you can find the documentation here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-first